# Prove that all prime divisors of $7a^2(a+1)-1$ are of the form $7k\pm1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

**Question:**

> Let a be a positive integer. Prove that all prime divisors of $7a^2(a+1)-1$ are of the form $7k\pm1$

$a$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$ .

Comment: How do you know this is true? What is the source?

Comment: Are you sure you've quoted this problem correctly? How is $7k \pm 1$ a "prime divisor"?

Comment: I don't know how to prove this, but, three observations.  
1. Checking by computer, this is true for the first 100,000 values of a.   
2. It's clear that $7a^2(a+1)-1$ is congruent to $-1 mod 7$.    
3. The discriminant of $7a^2(a+1)-1$ is 49.

Answer (score 4):

It gets complicated, but this is Corollary 10 in [this paper on cubic reciprocity](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0611151).